# Затирание "освобождённой" памяти

Tags: delphi, memory-management

Пишу некое приложение, которое работает с конфиденциальными (для меня) данными. Хочу чтобы, в идеале, после его работы в памяти не оставалось "хвостов" от этих данных.

В связи с этим возникла мысль: как известно, процедура SetLength() при увеличении размера строки/массива может выделить под него новый блок памяти и скопировать туда данные из старого, если ей не хватает места под новый размер в старом расположении.

Ну и собственно вопрос: возможно ли использовать такую обёртку (см. комментарий)?

```
procedure SecureResize(var Data: TBytes; NewSize: Integer);
var
  OldPtr: Pointer;
  OldSize: Integer;
begin
  OldPtr := Pointer(Data);
  OldSize := Length(Data);
  SetLength(Data, NewSize);
  if (OldSize < NewSize) and (OldPtr <> Pointer(Data)) then 
  begin {
      Данные были перемещены, поэтому необходимо затереть их в старой
      локации. Формально, OldPtr указывает на "свободный" участок памяти, 
      но может ли его за это время занять другой процесс или можно
      гарантировать что в этом месте он ещё никем не занят и спокойно 
      затереть данные?.. }
    FillChar(OldPtr^, OldSize, 0);
  end else if OldSize > NewSize then
    FillChar(Data[NewSize], OldSize - NewSize, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Никто не будет искать следы от приложения "после его работы", тем более что после завершения процесса будет непонятно где искать, поскольку память вернется системе. А вот снять дамп (несколько) пока процесс выполняется - это да, легко. Предлагаемый вами метод не потокобезопасен.

Comment: @kami, непотокобезопасен - это понятно и решаемо, но в данном случае приложение однопоточное. А вот от дампов - вполне себе защита, т.к. данные находятся в памяти короткое время, пока их смотришь.

Comment: Не совсем. Это с точки зрения пользователя - "короткое время". А чужой программный код успел за это время миллион раз внедриться к вам в процесс (или даже не внедряясь), снять нужные данные "пока на них смотришь" и исчезнуть. Для защиты критичных данных от несанкционированного считывания лучше обратите внимание на защиту кода. Ну а если берем именно рассматриваемый узкий случай - посмотрите, как сделаны менеджеры памяти. Например FastMM. Измените методы высвобождения и реаллокации и подчищайте память в них. Это будет глобальнее, чем чистить только TBytes.

Comment: Upd к предыдущему комментарию: в FastMM есть директива AlwaysClearFreedMemory

Comment: Так в том и суть, что мне не нужно постоянно очищать, только в паре мест.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использовать указатель после освобождений нельзя - это грубейшая ошибка. Выделяй память нужного размера самостоятельно.
2. Используй [`RtlSecureZeroMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562768(v=vs.85).aspx), поскольку обнуление неиспользуемой памяти может быть выкинуто оптимизатором.

Comment: Да, в итоге так и сделал (правда через FillChar), просто смущает то что не всегда необходимо перемещать старые данные в новый блок, а в этом случае они так перемещаются каждый раз.

Comment: @Alekcvp, а что мешает самому сравнить размеры?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что SetLength при увеличении буфера не всегда выделяет новый блок памати, а чаще всего увеличивает существующий. Переносит только когда места не хватает для увеличения. А я так не смогу, поэтому придётся _всегда_ выделять новый буфер и копировать туда старые данные.

Comment: @Alekcvp, ты можешь сделать свой класс, который будет иметь некоторый запас и по возможности расширяться без перевыделения.

Comment: Не могу, потому что эти TBytes изначально выделяются в сторонней библиотеке :(

Answer (score 1):

В "такой обёртке" есть вероятность AV, так как старые страницы могут уже быть 'MEM_RELEASE'.

Можно просто создать новый массив-копию и после подчистить старый.

```
procedure SecureResize(var Data: TBytes; Len: Integer);
var
  NewData : TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(NewData, Len);
  if ( Len > Length(Data) )
    then Len := Length(Data);
  if ( Len > 0 ) then begin
    Move(Data[0], NewData[0], Len);
    FillChar(Data[0], Length(Data), $00);
  end;
  Data := NewData;
end;
```

Но, думаю, конструктивнее создать для таких данных (инкапсулировать их в) класс,
в котором переопределить FreeInstance под свои нужды.